# Two Objects Created from the Same Class, isinstance = False

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unittest

I'm trying to create some unit tests for some code here at work.

The code takes in an object and based on information within that object imports a specific module then creates an instance of it.

The test I am trying to write creates the object and then I check that it is an instance of the class I expect it to import. The issue is the isinstance check is failing.

Here is what my test looks like.

```
import importlib
from path.to.imported_api import SomeApi

api = importlib.import_module("path.to.imported_api").create_instance()  # create_instance() is a function that returns SomeApi().

assert isinstance(api, SomeApi)  # This returns false, but I am not sure why.
```

Comment: You say you're writing unit tests. Have you mocked anything?

Comment: Without knowing what `create_instance` does it could return anything. You probably need to include `type(api)` and `type(api) is SomeApi`. It could also be that you import the module twice by using `importlib` in which case it could be the same class but due to the reloading it's not considered identical.

Comment: -1  This is too dumbed down code example to actually reproduce anything.  Since you have `from path.to.imported_api import SomeApi` just above, the dynamic importlib line will not do anything, it will just use the already existing module sitting in `sys.modules`.

Comment: @wim Not necessarily, I had some weird cases where `import_module` did load the module again. I don't remember what caused this anymore though.

Comment: @MSeifert  yes, necessarily.  it's the exact same path twice:  "path.to.imported_api".

Comment: create_instance() simply returns an instance of SomeApi(), that is all.

My questions is why is the object I create using import_module not an instance of SomeApi() even though they both have the same exact output when doing a type()?

Comment: You have to edit your question to show the real differences between the import like `from path.to.imported_api import SomeApi` and the import like `importlib.import_module("path.to.imported_api")`.  And you should probably include the code for the `create_instance()` function too.  At the moment, this is not a satisfactory [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and your question will be downvoted and [likely] closed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the difference is, that whereas both objects refer to the same module, they get different identifiers as you load a new module and bypass sys.modules. See also the explanation here: https://bugs.python.org/issue40427

A hack might be to compare the name:

```
assert isinstance(api.__class__.__name__, SomeApi.__name__)
```

Answer (score -2):

There are a few things that could cause that:
So first, it could be that the api is just returning something that looks like SomeApi(). Also it coud is be that SomeApi is overwriting isinstance behaviour.